# Android layout xml file syntax error

Tags: android, android-layout

have this layout css:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:scrollbars="vertical">  
    <LinearLayout  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:orientation="vertical"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/add_problem_form_title"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="@string/feedbacktitle"  
            android:textSize="10pt">  
        </TextView>  

        <EditText  
            android:id="@+id/problem_name"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:hint="@string/feedbackname"  
            android:inputType="textPersonName"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
        </EditText>         

        <EditText  
            android:id="@+id/problem_text"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:hint="@string/feedbackbody"  
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"  
            android:lines="5"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
        </EditText>

        <Button  
            android:id="@+id/button_send_feedback"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="@string/feedbackbutton"  
            android:onClick="sendFeedback"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
        </Button>               

    </LinearLayout>  
</ScrollView> 

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First, add the problem you want to solve!"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/add_problem_text"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add a Problem You Want To See Solved"
    />    

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/add_problem_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add a Problem"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/browse_problems_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Browse Problems"

    />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/search_problems_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search Problems"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/my_problems_button"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="View My Problems"
    />    
</LinearLayout>
```

The system says I put it together incorrectly. I added the stuff on top to make a form, but I guess this isn't the way it is meant to be done.

What is the correct way to arrange these elements?  By the way, there are UI elements from 2 different views here. Is that ok?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **MUST** have only **one** root element.

Let's try this, I have just added the root LinearLayout and fill its parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <ScrollView  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:scrollbars="vertical">  
        <LinearLayout  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:orientation="vertical"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/add_problem_form_title"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:text="@string/feedbacktitle"  
                android:textSize="10pt">  
            </TextView>  

            <EditText  
                android:id="@+id/problem_name"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:hint="@string/feedbackname"  
                android:inputType="textPersonName"  
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
            </EditText>         

            <EditText  
                android:id="@+id/problem_text"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:hint="@string/feedbackbody"  
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"  
                android:lines="5"  
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
            </EditText>

            <Button  
                android:id="@+id/button_send_feedback"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:text="@string/feedbackbutton"  
                android:onClick="sendFeedback"  
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
            </Button>               

        </LinearLayout>  
    </ScrollView> 

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First, add the problem you want to solve!"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_problem_text"    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add a Problem You Want To See Solved"
        />    

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_problem_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add a Problem"
        />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/browse_problems_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Browse Problems"

        />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_problems_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search Problems"
        />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_problems_button"        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View My Problems"
        />    
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```